# How to close task manager with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to close task manager using the following taskkill command:

```
taskkill /f /im Taskmgr.exe
```

But it tells me that I can't because there is an error, I lack access.

Is there any way to acquire those permissions with a more complex taskkill or something along those lines?

If that's not possible,here's the code I'm using,there might be a way to substitute the taskkill for an Alt + F4 or another method,all ideas are welcome

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
do
Set colProcessList = GetObject("Winmgmts:").ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
If objProcess.name = "Taskmgr.exe" then
vFound = True
End if
Next

If vFound = True then
objShell.Run "taskkill /f /im Taskmgr.exe", , True
vFound = False
End If
loop
```

Comment: What possible valid reason is there to programmically kill the Task Manager process?

Comment: If I'm honest, I simply want to mess with people. I mean,I won't destroy a computer or anything,but I'd like to install something like this in a friend's PC for a while. I got nothing else

Comment: Pretty much what I expected.

Comment: So.... you got any tips? Nothing has consistenly worked so far,and I haven't been able to test Hackoo's code yet. So any tips to fix my code will help me a lot

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, accepting an answer that doesn't solve your problem helps no one. People will assume the question is answered and move on, not to mention most will move on anyway due to the post content. The people this posts will attract are those wanting a quick rep hit and nothing more. Eventually it will get cleaned up and closed. Enjoy the tip.

Comment: I'll try luck with the code below,thanks for the tips,I forgot to un-tick the answer,at first I thought it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This vbscript can did the trick :

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else
Do
    Call KillProcess("TaSkMgR.ExE")
Loop
End If
'*************************************************************************************
Sub KillProcess(MyProcess)
Dim colProcessList,objProcess
Set colProcessList = GetObject("Winmgmts:").ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    If LCase(objProcess.name) = LCase(MyProcess) then
        objProcess.Terminate()
    End if
Next
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'*********************************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 3):

I have no excel by myself to try it out, but maybe a:

```
If objProcess.name = "Taskmgr.exe" then
    objProcess.Terminate()
End if
```

would work

Comment: Well.... I've tested it a bit more.... It works the first few times,but for some reason it stops working after the third or so time.... I don't know why

Comment: Terminate method should return integer, which is the code number of error which occured. Maybe this would help

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not very good at coding. Is there any modification I can make to solve the problem?

Comment: @nicochulo Check my answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim wshShell : Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Exec "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Task Manager"""
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "taskkill /im Taskmgr.exe", , True
```

this works on my non admin account so maybe it will work with your purposes